# Idiom for keeping user state during login with react-aad-msal

Tags: react-aad-msal

I'm using [react-aad-msal](https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad/) and need to keep some state from before to after the login. Normally with Azure AD I would pass the state that I need to persist across login in the [userState parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#use-a-state-parameter) but this [is not implemented](https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad/issues/249) in react-aad-msal.  With such a popular library, I can't possibly be the only one who needs to persist state across a login.  What is a good idiom for persisting state across the re-direct cycles?